# Unbind C-d from Delete in Emacs

Tags: linux, emacs

On my system (Ubuntu 11.04) C-d acts as an alias to Delete in emacs. Is there a way to break this connection? If so, how?

Comment: Just curious, but … why? :-) I see people asking about ^[ZXCV] all the time, even ^W sometimes, but I think this is a first for ^D.

Comment: @BRPocock I prefer kill-word to be C-d, not M-d.

Comment: Ah, OK. :-) Just wondering, since there isn't a “well-known shortcut” of the MacOS-variety with which C-d would conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your emacs init file:

```
(global-unset-key "\C-d")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to unbind <kbd>C-d</kbd> first if you want to rebind it to "kill-word", even when another key sequence is already bound to it. Just put

```
(global-set-key "\C-d" 'kill-word)
```

in your .emacs file. Now, both <kbd>C-d</kbd> and <kbd>M-d</kbd> will be bound to "kill-word", the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key is unaffected from this change. Of course, if <kbd>M-d</kbd> is somehow in the way for you, you could unset <kbd>M-d</kbd> using

```
(global-unset-key "\M-d")
```

In general, note that any major- or minor-mode may re-bind these keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

`C-d` is universally bound to delete, but if you don't like it, use `global-set-key` and set `C-d` to something else, say `undefined`. You might still need to set it something else in some modes, which enhance the functionality by binding it some mode-specific command (e.g. hungry delete in programming modes)

EDIT: This works for me:

```
(global-set-key [delete] 'delete-backward-char)
(global-set-key [C-d] 'undefined)
```

The first one seems to break the alias connection

Comment: The thing is I want to rebind C-d without changing the behavior of delete.